# Booting fails on ThinkPad x1 - USB and DVD

Tags: boot, 18.04, thinkpad

Trying to install 18.04 desktop & server, but booting fails with both. 
Tried creating USB with rufus.
Tried native Win7 AND Win10 burning. DVD boots on Dell Precision 7520, but not on the ThinkPad.
ThinkPad errors:
- USB stick boot cycles with "invalid media boot:"
- DVD hangs with "ISOLINUX 6.0.3 20171017 ETCD..."

Checked BIOS settings include Legacy and UEFI Both.

The system *will* boot from a ~2017 Mint DVD I have - so it seems like it is related to the Ubuntu images.

I am burning an 18.10 image now as a test - but would rather have the LTS version.

Advice?
Thanks!!
Jim

Comment: OK - now *this* is weird. 18.10 starts to boot. Shows (briefly) an Ubuntu splash screen, then immediately reboots on its own.

Comment: More details - I downloaded Mint 19.01 Cinnamon and get the same error. The common thread seems to be "ISOLINUX 6.0.3 20171017 ETCD..." and it never proceeds from there. The Mint 18.1 image boots perfectly (Note - this is a DVD from Linux Format magazine, which has 3 distros on it - but Mint 18.01 64 bit boots fine)

Answer (score 1):

Eureka! (or something like that)
Finally found the issue was with the BIOS on the Thinkpad X1
I was running N14ET32W (1.10) from 8/13/2015 as reported by msinfo32.
After going to the Lenovo support site and searching - I found N14ET49W (1.27) and ran through the update.
Booted successfully into 18.04-2 and the install went perfectly.
Hope this may help someone else.

Jim

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)